# 'Enter' is instantly submitting questions and answers on Android

Tags: support, android-app, posting, keyboard

How are you supposed to to start a new paragraph or line break on here using a basic keyboard? Or maybe I should ask "What's the preferred method?", as using the normal button (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) will post a question or comment and not a line break.

This happens when using Chrome or the Stack Exchange app on Android. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> button posts on either questions, answers, or comments. I have figured out to now do what I want using basic HTML, however not everyone will do this. It could also be the reason why I am seeing extremely long questions that are quite hard to read.

I understand about not having breaks in the comments. It's the answer and questions part I can't work out.

Comment: What sort of browser are you using?  Unless you're writing a comment, Enter should start a new line.

Comment: Using Chrome or the StackExchange App on Android the (Enter) button posts on either answers or comments. I have figured out to now do what I want using basic HTML, however not everyone will do this, could also be the reason why I am seeing extremely long questions that're quite hard to read

Comment: That sounds like a configuration issue on your end; Enter is *supposed* to line break.

Comment: @DanK: Comments can't have line breaks in them so Enter is supposed to post them. A comment should not be something long enough to *need* line breaks, which is why they don't appear.

Comment: I understand about not having breaks in the comments, it's the Answer and Questions part I can't work out

Comment: What phone model and keyboard app are you using? Note that different keyboard apps might have different behavior, and while the SE Android app overrides the IME option to "Next" on the Title text field, it doesn't override the IME option on the Body text field (e.g. Gboard line-break well with the Enter key).

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes...just because you're not able to reproduce a given bug in the app doesn't mean it doesn't occur or that the OP's report is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

When typing a question (or an answer), hitting Enter will just add a new line to the post you're editing. Proof follows below:*

Comments are designed to be short, and are therefore limited to single lines. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> conveniently submits the comment; once you're used to it, you'll appreciate the shortcut.

The Enter button on my Android phone and iPhone have the exact same behavior as the Enter key on my MacBook.

*<sub>: except that you can't see which keys I'm pressing ... You just have to take my word for it.</sub>

Comment: Not from my end, I know it should, add a new line but it doesn't. To do this I have had to use P or B in tags

Comment: @VoteDukakis The asker says pressing Enter posts the question, not that it doesn't render properly.